# Prime race modulo $12$. When is the first sign change?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Define $\pi(x;q,a)$ as the number of primes less than or equal
to $x$ which are congruent to $a$ modulo $q$.

Up to $x=10^{11}$ we have $\pi(x;12,1) \le \pi(x;12,-1)$.

What is the smallest $x$ for which $\pi(x;12,1) > \pi(x;12,-1)$?

Assuming GRH the sign changes infinitely often.

Comment: The sign of $\pi(x;q,a)- \pi(x;q,b)$ changes infinitely often unconditionally, this is because otherwise $\sum_n \Lambda(n) n^{-s} (1_{n \equiv a \bmod q}-1_{n \equiv b \bmod q})$ would have a pole at $s= \sigma$ its abscissa of convergence. Finding the first "non-trivial pole" should give some hints on the first sign change.

Comment: @reuns, what you've written is not correct; look up Chebyshev's bias.

Comment: @reuns, there is an issue using partial summation to move from $\psi(x;q,a)$ to $\pi(x;q,a)$ that introduces an additional term that means that Landau's theorem may not work. As a toy model, see how Corollary 15.4 of Montgomery and Vaughan is only one-sided for $\pi(x)$ but two-sided for $\psi(x)$.

Comment: That being said, Jason Sneed has apparently proven unconditionally that this does indeed change sign infinitely often (see http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~ford/wwwpapers/barriersIII.pdf).

Comment: In any case, the first sign change is probably unknown. The usual way to find sign changes is well known and is based on the work of Ingham. It is the same method that Odlyzko and te Riele use to disprove Mertens conjecture.

Comment: Greg Martin discusses mod 12 races in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0010086.pdf (although he doesn't specifically consider the current question).

Comment: @reuns, no, this is incorrect. Landau's theorem only shows that $\psi(x;q,a) - \psi(x;q,b)$ changes sign infinitely often, but this is not enough to conclude that $\pi(x;q,a) - \pi(x;q,b)$ does too.

Comment: ...that's what I've been saying all along. In any case, it is certainly unknown unconditionally that for arbitrary $q$, $\pi(x;q,a) - \pi(x;q,b)$ changes sign infinitely often. Even under GRH, it could be the case that it does not change sign infinitely often (though this could only happen if the the imaginary ordinates of zeroes of certain Dirichlet $L$-functions were highly linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: @reuns, this is still missing the point. Try to make this rigorous and you will see that the issue is the second order term ($k = 2$ in your notation). Rubinstein and Sarnak show that under GRH $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log x} (\pi(x;q,a) - \pi(x;q,b)) = C + \sum_{\gamma} c_{\gamma} x^{i\gamma} + \cdots$ for certain constants $C, c_{\gamma}$, and the sum is over zeroes of certain Dirichlet $L$-functions. The problem is the term $C$, which you're neglecting.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Right tks, I found where is the problem (and what is your $C$) : $\displaystyle\sum_{p \le x} \chi(p) = \sum_{p^k \le x} \chi(p^k)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p^k \le x^{1/2}} \chi(p^k)^{\color{red}2}+ \mathcal{O}(x^{1/3})$ so $\sum_p \chi(p) p^{-s}$ has a singularity at $s=1/2$ if $\chi^2 = |\chi|$. You mentioned the structure of the imaginary zeros, is it complicated to see why (under GRH) $\pi(x;q,a)-\pi(x;q,b)$ changes of sign infinitely often in the OP's case ?

Comment: @reuns, yes, it is complicated; see Odlyzko and te Riele's paper for a similar proof. Basically you need to use many zeroes of these $L$-functions to overcome the constant $C$, which can be computationally quite demanding.

Answer (score 11):

The comments above point to the paper [Chebyshev's Bias](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1048515870) by Rubinstein and Sarnak, and the paper of [Martin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0010086.pdf).  For context, let's consider first primes mod $3$.

Assuming you're familiar with the terminology of Rubinstein and Sarnak, they compute the bias of primes to be $2$ mod $3$ over $1$ mod $3$ to be $0.9990\ldots$  (This is $\delta(P_{3;N;R})$ in their notation).  In 1978, [Bays and Hudson](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1978-32-142/S0025-5718-1978-0476616-X/S0025-5718-1978-0476616-X.pdf) computed that $608,981,813,029$ was the smallest integer $x$ such that $\pi_{3,2}(x)<\pi_{3,1}(x)$.

The paper of Martin shows the bias of primes to be $11$ mod $12$ over $1$ mod $12$ is *much* stronger: $\delta_{12;11,1}=0.999977$ (in Martin's slightly different notation.)  Since this is a logarithmic scale, the 'extra' $0.000977$ means that the bias is almost two orders of magnitude stronger.

Meanwhile, [Ford and Hudson](https://www.impan.pl/download/pdf/aa100-4-1) showed in that your $x$ will be less than $10^{84}$.